# How to check for platform within syslog-ng configuration?

Tags: syslog-ng

I run syslog-ng on several platforms with the default `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`, as well as an independent `/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/myconfig.conf`

In that specifc configuration I would like to reuse `s_src` from `syslog-ng.conf`, defined there as

```
source s_src {
       system();
       internal();
};
```

Unfortunately there are two problems which complicate my configuration:

- `s_src` is the default name on Debian, it is `s_sys` on CentOS (for the same source)
- it is not possible to have twice `internal()` as a source in a config (`syslog-ng` log shows `Multiple internal() sources were detected, this is not possible;`)

I am currently stuck with managing two identical sets of config files due to that single difference. Therefore:

- is it possible to conditionally use one source or another, depending on the platform (unfortunately, the platform is not part of the `ENV` variables)?
- or is a "soft-fail" possible - that is making so that syslog-ng does not stop parsing the configuration file upon an error? (in that case I would simply have two `log` entries with both sources, of which one would always fail for a given platform)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reset a source and recreate a common one using `internal()` again:

```
@define allow-config-dups 1
source s_src {};
source s_sys {};
source s_common {
       system();
       internal();
};
```